# Transform this list using linq?

Tags: linq

I'm trying to use LINQ to transform the following list.  LINQ should multiply each element against the next as long as the product is less than 15.  Additionally we should save the number of elements used to form the product.

```
int[] values = { 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 14 };  //assume Largest value will never be >= 15

1x3x4 = 12
2x7 = 14
14 = 14

{ {12,3}, {14,2}, {14,1} }
```

My ultimate goal is to take the geometric average of a very large list of numbers.  This is normally done by multiplying each element in the list together (1x3x4x2x7x14) then taking the nth root (in this case 1/6).

The obvious problem in using the "normal" method is that you will quickly find yourself using numbers beyond the maximum allowable number. You can workaround this by using the old divide and conquer method and with a little help from the natural log function.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have to use LINQ? Seems like you could easily achieve this just stepping through the array.

Answer (score 1):

> My ultimate goal is to take the geometric average of a very large list of numbers.

Then just take the nth root of each number and multiply afterwards.  Then you don't need to worry about splitting the list into groups:

```
double mean = 1.0;
foreach(int i in values)
{
    mean *= Math.Pow(i, 1.0 / values.Length);
}
```

Which *could* also be done in Linq with `Aggregate`:

```
mean = values.Aggregate(1.0, (prev, i) => prev * Math.Pow(i, 1.0 / values.Length ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is something like that build into standard LINQ method library. But you can easily create your own extension method. I called it `AggregateUntil`:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> AggregateUntil<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        TAccumulate seed,
        Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func,
        Func<TAccumulate, bool> condition,
        Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector
    )
    {
        TAccumulate acc = seed;
        TAccumulate newAcc;
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            newAcc = func(acc, item);
            if(!condition(newAcc))
            {
                yield return resultSelector(acc);
                acc = func(seed, item);
            }
            else
            {
                acc = newAcc;
            }
        }
        yield return resultSelector(acc);
    }
}
```

And now let's use it. First, take multiplications only, as long as they met `< 15` condition:

```
var grouped
    = values.AggregateUntil(1, (a,i) => a * i, a => a < 15, a => a).ToList();
```

Returns `List<int>` with 3 items: `12`, `14`, `14`. That's what you need. But now lets take number of items which were aggregated into each multiplication. That's easy using anonymous type::

```
int[] values = { 1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 14 };

var grouped
    = values.AggregateUntil(
        new { v = 1, c = 0 },
        (a, i) => new { v = a.v * i, c = a.c + 1 },
        a => a.v < 15,
        a => a).ToList(); ;
```

Returns exactly what you need:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well my solution is not quite as elegant as @MarcinJuraszek, but it's fast and it works within your constraints.

```
    int[] values = {1, 3, 4, 2, 7, 14};
    int product = 1;
    int elementsMultiplied = 0;
    List<Tuple<int,int>> allElements = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < values.Length ; i++)
    {
        product = product * values[i];
        elementsMultiplied++;
        if(i == values.Length - 1 || product * values[i+1] >= 15)
        {
            allElements.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(product, elementsMultiplied));
            product = 1;
            elementsMultiplied = 0;
        }
    }
    foreach(Tuple<int,int> pair in allElements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Item1 + "," + pair.Item2);   
    }
```